# android: how to retain clicked list item's pressed/selected state until pressing other items on list

Tags: android, android-listview

I want my list items to retain its pressed/selected state until I press other items on list. While typing this, I thought that I want it to work like RadioButtons without the circle buttons. I have tried setting the the list item's selected/pressed state true, or setting its background color on `onListItemClick` but when I do this, my list items stay clicked even after clicking other items. How can I unset the background color of the previously clicked items in the list? Or there is a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Step 1:** Try to reset background color(i.e your original background color) to all list items using for loop in `onItemClickListener()`.

**Step 2** :Set Different background color for selected one.

If you using Customized list View then it will be really easy.

**EDIT Customized List View Tutorial**

**[Custom ListView](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) and [this](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html)**

Video - [youtubeVideo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjAlNfa6obU)

Hope it helps

EDIT

Here's what I did: I iterated through the visible list to set the each item's background to transparent the setting the selected item's background a different color. This way, the color sticks until I press another item.

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    int childCount = l.getChildCount();

```
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
{
    View listItem = l.getChildAt(i);
    if(listItem != null )   listItem.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
}
v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pressed));
...
```

}

Comment: Hi, if I were to use customized list view, what do I have to do? I really don't want to iterate through all list items every time I click an item...

Comment: sorry, not really getting your point. I know how to use a customized adapter.. But what I mean is, how do I change back the background color of the previously clicked items? Is there a listener for an item if it gets unselected or or something?

Comment: sorry, i think what i said in my answer is one of the way to achieve your goal.. i used this for more than two apps its really working nice

Comment: hi, sorry it took me a while to get back on this answer. i resorted to your answer so i'll gonna accept it. will also post my what i did. thanks!