# save the state of the check box items in a multiple choice list view

Tags: android

Here i am using a content provider to get all the contacts and put it in a list with multiple choice,now i want to save the checked names to the shared preference.
Next time when the activity is opened the checked items should be present.

I am new to android.
thanks in advance.....

here is my code...

```
public class Blacklist extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences pref,selected;
    String phoneNo, s;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    SharedPreferences.Editor select;
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> blocked = new ArrayList<String>();

    ContentResolver mcursor;
    ListView con;
    ArrayList<String> al;
    ArrayList<String> ph;
    static ArrayList<String> checked;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blacklist);
        con = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
        al = new ArrayList<String>();

        checked = new ArrayList<String>();
        // get contacts
        Cursor cur = getContacts();

        // display contacts
        if (cur != null) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String name = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                al.add(name);

            }

            // create an array adapter

            ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, al);
            con.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            con.setAdapter(ad);

            // to find the selected names
            con.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int kunk = 0;
                    ph = new ArrayList<String>();
                    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = con
                            .getCheckedItemPositions();

                    for (int i = 0; i < con.getCount(); i++) {
                        selected= getSharedPreferences("SELECTED", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        select=selected.edit();
                        if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) {

                            select.putBoolean("bool "+arg1, true);


                            String check = con.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                            if (!temp.contains(check)) {
                                // get the no
                                Cursor cursor; // Cursor object
                                String mime; // MIME type
                                int dataIdx; // Index of DATA1 column
                                int mimeIdx; // Index of MIMETYPE column
                                int nameIdx; // Index of DISPLAY_NAME column

                                // Get the name
                                cursor = getContentResolver()
                                        .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                                                null, null, null);
                                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    nameIdx = cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

                                    // Set up the projection
                                    String[] projection = {
                                            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1,
                                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE };

                                    // Query ContactsContract.Data
                                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                            projection,
                                            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
                                                    + " = ?",
                                            new String[] { check }, null);

                                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                        // Get the indexes of the MIME type and
                                        // data
                                        mimeIdx = cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE);
                                        dataIdx = cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1);

                                        // Match the data to the MIME type,
                                        // store in variables
                                        do {
                                            ArrayList<String> phtemp = new ArrayList<String>();
                                            mime = cursor.getString(mimeIdx);

                                            if (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(mime)) {
                                                phoneNo = cursor
                                                        .getString(dataIdx);
                                                phoneNo = PhoneNumberUtils
                                                        .formatNumber(phoneNo);
                                                ph.add(phoneNo);
                                                if (!phtemp.contains(ph)) {

                                                    phtemp.add(phoneNo);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                    if (ph != null) {
                        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet();
                        hs.addAll(ph);
                        ph.clear();
                        ph.addAll(hs);

                        for (String l : hs) {

                            // save list in shared preference
                            pref = getSharedPreferences("MY_LOG", MODE_PRIVATE);                                                                                
                            edit = pref.edit();
                            kunk++;
                            s = Integer.toString(kunk);

                            edit.putString(s, l);

                        }
                        edit.putString("size", s);
                        edit.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "saved to shared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // retrieve the values of blocked numbers and store it
                        // in an array block list
                        pref = getSharedPreferences("MY_LOG", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String un = pref.getString("size", "0");

                        for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(un); i++) {
                            String no = pref.getString("" + i, "nill");
                            String non = returnNumberOnly(no);
                                    .
                            blocked.add(non);
                        }

                    }

                }
            });

        } else {

        }

    }

    String returnNumberOnly(String number) {
        String ss[] = number.split("\\+91");
        String numberArray[] = null;
        if (ss.length == 2) {
            numberArray = ss[1].split("-");
        } else if (ss.length == 1) {
            numberArray = ss[0].split(" ");
        }
        number = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
            number += numberArray[i];
        }
        System.out.println("------------------ IN returnNumberOnly Fn ------ "
                + number + " RETURNED ------------------------------------ ");
        return number;
    }

    private Cursor getContacts() {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor c;
        mcursor = getContentResolver();
        c = mcursor.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did u google anything?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11601129/2591002)

Comment: see this example..it would hep you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715556/removing-muliple-items-from-listview-using-check-box-in-android

Comment: Store the checked position in an array list and pass that list in shared preference

Comment: @RahulGupta we can store the item position in the shared preference but how to set the items checked when the next time the activity is started..that is how to set the item checked if the position is stored in the shared preference

Comment: @SweetWisher it is not a custom list so i dunno whether that link could help

Comment: If ypu want "how to set the items checked when the next time the activity is started" : you have to make custom adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView on item click listener :-

```
final Integer index = Integer.valueOf(position);

            if(!checkedPositions.contains(index))//This is a global array list which contains the checked item states
                checkedPositions.add(index);
            else
                checkedPositions.remove(index);

            check.setChecked(checkedPositions.contains(index));
```

Inside GetView()listener :-

```
holder.checkbox1.setChecked(flag);
            if(flag){
                if(!checkedPositions.contains(position))
                    checkedPositions.add(position);
            }
            else
            {
                checkedPositions.clear();
            }
            final Integer index = Integer.valueOf(position);
        holder.checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        if(!checkedPositions.contains(index))
                            checkedPositions.add(index);
                    }
                    else
                        checkedPositions.remove(index);


                }
            });
            holder.checkbox1.setChecked(checkedPositions.contains(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the list in Shared Preference.

Next time your activity starts, retrieve the array list using shared preference.

Put a if condition in `getView()` that if the array list contains position then set checkbox status as checked.

For example :-

```
if(array_list.get(position) == listview_item) // Just for reference. Not actual code
    checkbox1.setChecked(true);
else    
    checkbox1.setChecked(false);
```

I hope you got it.

Comment: i am using a multiple choice list view ,then what should come in place of checkbok1....how to check that particular item checked

Comment: Multiple Choice ? In your listview there is only one checbox per item right ?

Comment: yes one checkbox per item..how to use that item in the arraylist to set checked i cant specify checkbox.setChecked(true); right.